# How to select records around another record's timestamp?

Tags: mysql

Being hammering my head on this one: I need to select all records up or down "nearby" another record's timestamp within n minutes. The examples I have seen uses NOW() but the issue I have is that I need to use a record's timestamp not the current time. Example:

```
ID      timestamp
851     2020-04-17 12:56:02     
850     2020-04-17 09:40:01     
849     2020-04-17 09:39:02     
848     2020-04-17 09:39:01     
847     2020-04-17 09:36:02     
**846   2020-04-17 09:36:02**   
845     2020-04-17 09:36:02     
844     2020-04-17 09:36:01     
843     2020-04-17 09:36:01     
842     2020-04-17 09:31:01     
841     2020-04-17 09:11:02     
840     2020-04-16 22:13:02
```

Say I will use record ID 846 as main timestamp, and want to get all records around it within 5 minutes, the result I look forward should be: 850 to 842, excluding 851 and 841, 840. **How in the world I can do that?** :)

---

So finally, to get those records within one minute, I got something using this (I will know forehand which will be the record Id to be used as main point to find nearby records):

```
SELECT
    Id, 
    date_in,
FROM t 
WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, date_in,
                        (SELECT date_in FROM t WHERE Id = 846)
                    ) = 0 
       )
ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 20

ID      timestamp
847     2020-04-17 09:36:02
**846   2020-04-17 09:36:02**
845     2020-04-17 09:36:02
844     2020-04-17 09:36:01
843     2020-04-17 09:36:01
```

Comment: Go on. Try something .

Comment: Add an addition to your `WHERE` clause that limits the IDs to the ones you want.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't know the resultant IDs at this point, in fact, that's what I need at the end.

Answer (score 0):

So to use a range bigger than 1 minute I came up with this, works fine but I don't know if is the correct way. This is to pick records within 20 minutes using one's timestamp as starting point:

```
SELECT
    Id, 
    date_in,
FROM t 
WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, date_in,
                        (SELECT date_in FROM t WHERE Id = 846)
                    ) = < 20 
       )
       AND
       (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, date_in,
                        (SELECT date_in FROM t WHERE Id = 846)
                    ) = > -20 
       )
ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 20

ID      timestamp
850     2020-04-17 09:40:01     
849     2020-04-17 09:39:02     
848     2020-04-17 09:39:01     
847     2020-04-17 09:36:02     
**846   2020-04-17 09:36:02**   
845     2020-04-17 09:36:02     
844     2020-04-17 09:36:01     
843     2020-04-17 09:36:01     
842     2020-04-17 09:31:01
```